# update multiple-choice checkbox in a database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, multiple-choice

**Multiselect option**

For example, a user with the id of '10' has the option to choose what languages he speaks.
He chooses each language using a "multiple select" or "multiple checkboxes", like these:

```
<input name="lang[]" value="en" type="checkbox" />
<input name="lang[]" value="es" type="checkbox" />
<input name="lang[]" value="jp" type="checkbox" />
```

What I want to know is, how does the db table that stores these options look like and how would the server side php insert/update them?

**My guess so far**

What I'm imagining is that the table will look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_langs (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, lang VARCHAR, fk_user INT);
```

While to INSERT the values into a new user, php does a simple insert loop:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user_langs (lang,fk_user) VALUES(?,?)');
foreach($_POST['lang'] as $lang){
    $stmt->execute(array($lang, $user_id));
}
```

The problem I'm getting is with UPDATES, the simplest way would be to delete all the existing entries of this user, and insert the new ones.

```
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM user_langs WHERE fk_user=?');
$stmt1->execute(array($user_id));
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user_langs (lang,fk_user) VALUES(?,?)');
foreach($_POST['lang'] as $lang){
    $stmt2->execute(array($lang, $user_id));
}
```

But I think this will over increment the primary id too quickly if it's actively used, even if the upper limits of the id are astronomical I don't like the idea of polluting my database, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong, so I would like to know how the pro's handle it.

Comment: "this will over increment the primary id too quickly" --- so what?

Comment: if this is how it's supposed to be handled, then say so, and I will be on my merry way.

Comment: they are not *excessive*. Id has no any business meaning. Who cares whether it is 42 or 42424242 pk value? I don't.

Comment: The way you describe is the way I always do it. I'd be interested if there's a better way though. But this way seems simplest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to come from the fact that the id in the above example is artificial, the solution is to use [multi-column primary keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) also called [Compound key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) which I was unaware about when I asked the question.

The solution then becomes to use a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_langs (
  lang VARCHAR, 
  fk_user INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY(lang,fk_user)
);
```

This improves data integrity because a single user can no longer have 2 entries of the same language.

To insert a value you do the same:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user_langs (lang,fk_user) VALUES(?,?)');
foreach($_POST['lang'] as $lang){
    $stmt->execute(array($lang, $user_id));
}
```

And the simplest way to handle an update is to delete all entries bound to this user, and insert the correct ones again in the same manner:

```
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM user_langs WHERE fk_user=?');
$stmt1->execute(array($user_id));
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user_langs (lang,fk_user) VALUES(?,?)');
foreach($_POST['lang'] as $lang){
    $stmt2->execute(array($lang, $user_id));
}
```

You can also do it like [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) suggests, to SELECT all the languages, then run array_diff to find the old and new values, and delete the old ones and insert the new ones, but this means running 3 queries and comparing results, while in case of languages it is very rare for a user to speak more than 3, which is why just deleting and inserting again seems like the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use some kind of diffs.

Algorithm:

1. User posted the form with selected languages
2. You select current languages
3. Using `array_diff()` twice (diff between old and new, and opposite one) you get 2 arrays of languages which you need to delete, and which you need to add
4. According to the arrays from 3 you perform one `INSERT` and one `DELETE` query